# Redirect https .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http, https

Heey everyone so i recently added https to a website and now i have a small problem with the redirect if someone goes to the website without www.

they go to the following url

example: https://www.example.com/https://example.com

instead of going to https://example.com

Code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^koenschenk.nl [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]
{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.koenschenk.nl/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

Redirect 301 https://koenschenk.nl https://www.koenschenk.nl
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Comment: The only thing I noticed is that you are redirecting to http again with your last `RewriteRule`. When testing 301 redirects I would only do so with curl, as browsers tend to cache those aggressively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup redirection from HTTP to HTTPS by editing the following code in your `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` (supposing you're using a Linux machine.):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule / https://{koenschenk.nl}/
```

Place the mentioned lines of code in the .htaccess file in your website’s root folder.

Comment: I would like to be able to fix it in the .htaccess if possible

Comment: The code will exactly be the same irrespective of being placed in apahce2.conf or .htaccess file.

Comment: Oh allright my bad thanks for the answer.
When i try the code i get the following url. https://%7Bkoenschenk.nl%7D/